# A Guice-ready security framework?

Tags: security, guice, spring-security

Has anybody seen a framework which is either written to work with Guice or a library that integrates an existing security system (ie: Acegi) with Guice?

I have found the following thus far...

http://code.google.com/p/warp-security/ (I think this abandonware)

http://code.google.com/p/warp-security/ (no documentation)

Comment: Hi, you've written the same link two times. What was the other library? Did you eventually find some usable security framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache Shiro 1.2 and later has native support for Guice applications:

http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html

HTH!

Answer (score 5):

For whatever it's worth (being quite a late answer), I've had success integrating [Apache Shiro](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/) with Guice. Last time I checked, Acegi was too deeply dependent on Spring to be usable in a pure Guice solution. Shiro's documentation is a little lacking, but the API is pretty straight-forward and easy to use, if don't mind a little digging.

---

In case it's of any interest, I've posted a [Gist of the simplest example I could find](https://gist.github.com/869205). Two caveats:

1. It's written against a pre-release version of Shiro 1.0
2. The Active Directory realm we're using is a somewhat modified version from the main Shiro source, using some ideas from [the Active Directory plugin for Jenkins (then Hudson)](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin).

Hopefully, it's enough to get you started...

Comment: have you shared this as an open source project, I believe many would like this functionality?

Comment: @tranced_UT3: There isn't much to share. The Guice integration bit was as simple as wiring up a [SecurityManager](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/mgt/SecurityManager.html) with one or more [Realms](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/Realm.html). Shiro realms are generally easily configurable through setters (for my app, all this is < 200 LOC) The hard part of using Shiro is plugging it in to the rest of the application stack you are using (this is a clear differentiator of SpringSecurity)